# Get return value of exe in script

Tags: c, bash, shell

I want to run a exe having command line arguments in a script. Based on the return of this exe, I need to execute further steps. Is it possible to get the return of this exe?

```
#!/bin/bash
./getDisplayWidth "FullHD"
if [ "<return value of getDisplayWidth "FullHD">" == "0" ]; then
       echo "SUCCESS"
else
       echo "FAILED"
fi
```

Comment: Note, while the duplicate indicates a C program, it's the same for anything. `$?` has the exit status of the last program ran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either test the result to see if it is 0 (success) directly using "if", like this:

```
if ./getDisplayWidth "FullHD"; then
```

Or you can run the script and then use $? to refer to it's return value:

```
./getDisplayWidth
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
```

Answer (score 2):

`$?` will give you the last exit code of an executed command/app.

You can run your app as normal and then immediately after check what `$?` has returned and based on that tweak your script logic.

Some nice reference on the `$?` variable can be found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/bash-shell-exit-status/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
if ./getDisplayWidth "FullHD"; then
       echo "SUCCESS"
else
       echo "FAILED"
fi
```

The if already tests for exit code `0`
In Unix this is the idiomatic way of checking for success.